# What is the difference between rdf:resource and rdfs:Resource?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, rdf-xml

In RDF 1.1 XML Syntax documentation **`rdf:resource`** is used as a shortened form when defining [Empty Property Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-empty-property-elements):

> When a predicate arc in an RDF graph points to an object node which has no further predicate arcs, which appears in RDF/XML as an empty node element   (or ) this form can be shortened. This is done by using the IRI of the object node as the value of an XML attribute `rdf:resource` on the containing property element and making the property element empty.

In RDF Schema 1.1 **`rdfs:Resource`** is defined as a [class](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_resource):

> All things described by RDF are called resources, and are instances of the class `rdfs:Resource`. This is the class of everything. All other classes are subclasses of this class. `rdfs:Resource` is an instance of `rdfs:Class`.

How are the two related? Does an `rdf:resource` value always belong to `rdfs:Resource` class and the other way around?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not related, at all. They just happen to share a name because they both have *something* to do with resources.

The term "resource" is central to the RDF data model (it's *Resource* Description Framework, after all). A resource in RDF is, very generally speaking, anything that can be identified by a URI (there's heaps of technical details regarding how things like blank nodes and literals fall under this definition, but for simplicity's sake we'll ignore that here).

`rdf:resource` is just a syntax element in the RDF/XML syntax, namely an attribute to identify the resource that is the property value. For example, here's a simple RDF model (1 triple), in RDF/XML:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Bob">
    <foaf:address rdf:resource="http://example.org/address1"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Here, `http://example.org/Bob` is the subject resource, and `foaf:address` is a property of that subject (used to link the subject resource to a value). The property value in this case is also a resource (`http://example.org/address1`), so in the RDF/XML syntax we use `rdf:resource` attribute to link it. If you were to write the same RDF model in a different syntax though (for example, Turtle), you wouldn't see `rdf:resource` appear at all:

```
<http://example.org/Bob> foaf:address <http://example.org/address1> .
```

In RDF Schema, the class `rdfs:Resource` is the class of all resources. It is a concept, not a syntax-specific mechanism. Since pretty much anything in RDF is a resource, it is the 'top-level' class of things. All things are resources, so if you introduce a new class, for example "Person", it will (automatically) be a subclass of `rdfs:Resource`.

```
<http://example.org/Bob> rdf:type <http://example.org/Person> . 
<http://example.org/Bob> rdf:type rdfs:Resource .
```

Note that the second triple is a logical consequence of the first triple. Therefore, in practice, the fact that bob is a Resource is almost never explicitly written down in RDF models - if needed, it can be inferred.